# Attributes Text in UITextView not working

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am using the code below to try and set the color of a substring of text in my `UITextView`, but it is not working. It seems like it should be simple; what am I missing?

```
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Welcome"];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:10];
[title addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];
[title addAttribute:kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];

descriptionCommentLabel.attributedText = title;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` with `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`. You can check a list of valid attributes in the constants section of this file: [Apple docs: NSAttributedString UIKit additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html). Your code would be now:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *title = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Welcome"];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:10];
[title addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];
[title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];
```

The `kCT...` attributes were used in iOS 5 and older versions, when UIKit didn't support `NSAttributedString` and you had to mess with CoreText.

Answer (score 1):

Change the below line in your code to:

```
[title addAttribute:kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];
```

to

```
[title addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeNamevalue:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, title.length)];
```